# Use local images in MvvmCross Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

In my Android project I have an image `icon.png`

Its build action is set to `AndroidResource`

It is in the drawable folder as well as in all the different definition folders.

In my Page I have added `<Image Source="icon.png"/>`

This causes a null exception to be thrown.

Am I missing something?

---

**EDIT**

I have updated to MvvmCross 5.3 and now there is no exception thrown. However the icon is still not shown.

Comment: Could you provide the whole exception or any screenshot on that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed for MvvmCross 5.3.1. This is a problem with forms needing the Assembly that contains the resources to be passed into its `Init()` method in order to know where to look for resources.

You can work around this by grabbing the latest Xamarin Forms activity and add it to your project [MvxFormsAppCompatActivity](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross-Forms/MvvmCross.Forms.Droid/Views/MvxFormsAppCompatActivity.cs) or [MvxFormsApplicationActivity](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross-Forms/MvvmCross.Forms.Droid/Views/MvxFormsApplicationActivity.cs). Remember to rename the class or change the namespace to not have it clash with the one from MvvmCross.

Comment: Even after updating to MvvmCross 5.3.2, the problem is still there.

Comment: There is a new piece of documentation that I suggest you read: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/forms/xamarin-forms-customization

Comment: Thank you, but it's unclear where to override that method.

Comment: In your activity that subclasses one of the mentioned Activities.